# WPF C# CefSharp GetElementByTagName Set Value, Class Button Click & Select ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I was using gecko but I have passed cefsharp because it is not wpf support and it looks pretty good. But I think the business logic is a bit different, I hope you help. I am using WPF and C#. NetFramework 4.5.2.

First of all, I have an entry panel and I have to log in.

```html
<form action="giris_kontrol.php" method="post">
<div class="login_input">
<input name="name" value="Kullanıcı Adı" onfocus="if(this.value=='Kullanıcı Adı') { this.value=''; }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value='Kullanıcı Adı' }"> 
<input type="password" name="pass" value=""> 
</div>
<div class="login_space"><input type="submit" value="Giriş" class="button_bu"></div>
</form>
```

TagNames: name, pass
Class: button_bu

And finally, how do I choose a combox like the one below?

```html
<select name="game_id" id="game"><option value="0">Select Game</option><option value="12">Crysis 1</option><option value="25">Crysis 2</option>.....
```

Thanks.